# Encryption and Decryption with KeyStore private key and iv goes wrong "Some times"

Tags: android, kotlin, encryption, keystore

I'm using Encryption and Decryption with KeyStore like this.

This is the flow. After i pass a string to encrypt method i save both encrypted and iv so i can retrive value with it later.Problem is some times, some encrypted values can not retrive correctly... not all of them! So think i encrypted 10 items and save them in some where( both encrypted and iv). Then when i wanna retrive one of them can not retrive correcly!

```
 init {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE)
        keyStore.load(null)
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
    }

  fun encryptData(text: String): Pair<ByteArray, String>? {
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKet(ALIAS))
            val iv = cipher.iv.toString(Charsets.ISO_8859_1)
            val result = cipher.doFinal(text.toByteArray(Charsets.ISO_8859_1))
            Timber.i("$TAG encrypted data $result")
            Timber.i("$TAG encrypted iv $iv")
            return if (result != null) {
                Pair(result, iv)
            } else {
                null
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.e("$TAG error encryptData", e)
            return null
        }
    }

fun decryptData(encryptedData: ByteArray, iv: ByteArray): String {
    return try {
        val spec = GCMParameterSpec(128, iv)
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getSecretKet(ALIAS), spec)
        val result = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData).toString(Charsets.ISO_8859_1)
        Timber.i("$TAG decrypted data $result")
        result
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.e("$TAG decryptData error may string was not encrypted", e)
        encryptedData.toString()
    }
}
```

And this is for get secret key. First i thougth may be problem is with my key, so I implemented it in this way and this class is singletone. But thing is some time when i re-open application some how this key is not same ( I think, because iv and encrypted value and also cipher are fixed). I also use **Charsets.ISO_8859_1** caue find that this charset is better to keep all characters and lose less.
Then I thought may be proble is with saving place so for test i just move from Room db with sstring field to SharePref with string. But the issue is same so now i'm prettry sure it is not about savig repository.

```
private fun getSecretKet(alias: String): Key {

    if (keyStore.containsAlias(alias)) {
        //Try for existing key
        return keyStore.getKey(alias, null)
    } else {
        //Key is not present, create new one.
        val keyGenerator = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val kGenerator =
                KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, ANDROID_KEY_STORE)
            val specs = KeyGenParameterSpec
                .Builder(
                    alias,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
                )
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                .build()
            kGenerator.init(specs)
            kGenerator
        } else {
            KeyGenerator.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
        }
        return keyGenerator.generateKey()
    }
}
```

I think this sould works as well as works mostly but eventually i can not get some of my encrypted data as I mentioned above. Any body have any idea?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Kotlin but it's generally a mistake to use String as a container for binary data like you are doing. If you have an sequence of arbitrary bytes that you must transform into a string then use a proper encoder for that purpose. A hex encoder is useful if you want to display the data for human analysis. Otherwise, use a base64 encoder, either standard or url-safe. I don't know if this is the cause of your problem.

Comment: I get your point, ok let me test it with base64 string.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk Do you mean need base64 when i passed it to cipher for encrypting or when i convert byte to string of iv to save?

Comment: cipher needs bytes for input, and returns bytes for output. First question: why are you trying to turn the output into a string? A byte array is a perfectly good first class citizen for holding and exchanging data.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk Caus i created a repository for saving this values and for start that repo implemented y shared pref and i thought may it better to convert it to string so that we can easilly create any repo that handle string. No it is saves in Room db. That is the reason.

Comment: Ok Mahdi, that makes sense. Then yes, you should encode it using base64 before saving it, and when you read it back in you should base-64 decode it back to bytes. I'm still not sure that the encoding issue is the source of your problems.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk Your solution is not work. I updated the question with your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnaly solve this issue by go more deep to AES changing implemtation.

1. The main thing was **IV**! In nutshell Iv is a tool for making encryption more complicated. We create an IV and pass it to cipher, cipher do encrypting data and mixing byte in many rounds and for blocks of bytes and in every round it updates IV with a logic and use it for next round or block of bytes. So if you get IV from cipher after finish encryption you will see that it changed!
2. Second thing is i imelemneted cipher singleTone but i change its creation encryption and decryption method itself. So every string for encoding will have new IV and after encoding finished I pass it with encrypted string to later decyption.

First I thought it will from string encryption with help of @PresidentJamesMovelenPolk but I test that with this impelemntation even with ISO_8859_1 it works well. And this is final impelemntationds:

```
 companion object {
    const val TRANSFORMATION = "AES/GCM/NoPadding"
    const val ANDROID_KEY_STORE = "AndroidKeyStore"
    const val ALIAS = "MyApp"
    const val TAG = "KeyStoreManager"
}

private var keyStore: KeyStore

init {
    keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE)
    keyStore.load(null)
}

fun encryptData(text: String): Pair<ByteArray, String>? {
    try {

        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION)
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKet(ALIAS))
        val iv = cipher.iv

        val result = cipher.doFinal(text.toByteArray(Charsets.ISO_8859_1))
        val resultIv = Base64.encodeToString(iv, Base64.NO_WRAP)
        Timber.i("$TAG encrypted data $result")
        Timber.i("$TAG encrypted iv $iv")
        return if (result != null) {
            Pair(result, resultIv)
        } else {
            null
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.e("$TAG error encryptData", e)
        return null
    }
}

fun encryptString(text: String): SecuredData? {
    return try {
        val result = encryptData(text)
        if (result != null) {
            SecuredData(result.first.toString(Charsets.ISO_8859_1), result.second)
        } else {
            null
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.e("$TAG error encryptString", e)
        null
    }
}

/**
 Get pair of encrypted value and iv
 */
fun decryptString(encryptedString: String, iv: String): String {
    return try {
        val result = decryptData(
            encryptedString.toByteArray(Charsets.ISO_8859_1),
            Base64.decode(iv, Base64.NO_WRAP)
        )
        result
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        Timber.e("Error in convert to Base64")
        encryptedString
    }
}

fun decryptData(encryptedData: ByteArray, iv: ByteArray): String {
    return try {
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION)
        val spec = GCMParameterSpec(128, iv)
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getSecretKet(ALIAS), spec)
        val result = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData).toString(Charsets.ISO_8859_1)
        Timber.i("$TAG decrypted data $result")
        result
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.e("$TAG decryptData error may string was not encrypted", e)
        encryptedData.toString()
    }
}

private fun getSecretKet(alias: String): Key {

    if (keyStore.containsAlias(alias)) {
        // Try for existing key
        return keyStore.getKey(alias, null)
    } else {
        // Key is not present, create new one.
        val keyGenerator = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val kGenerator =
                KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, ANDROID_KEY_STORE)
            val specs = KeyGenParameterSpec
                .Builder(
                    alias,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
                )
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                .build()
            kGenerator.init(specs)
            kGenerator
        } else {
            KeyGenerator.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE)
        }
        return keyGenerator.generateKey()
    }
}

@Keep
data class SecuredData(val value: String, val iv: String)
```